# Regex handling quoted parts as one word including escaping support

Tags: regex

I know there have already been questions very similar to this, but I couldn't find a regex handling `\"` as escaped quote.

Given the input:

```
he/l\"lo "//%$&$h w" t "" " "
```

...I want to have:

```
he/l\"lo
"//%$&$h w"
t
""
" "
```

My current state is

```
(\"|[^" ])+|"(\"|[^"])*"
```

which according to http://myregextester.com/index.php gives me

```
[0] => he/l\"lo
[1] => "//%$&$h
[2] => w"
[3] => t
[4] => ""
[5] => "
[6] => "
```

I am wondering why e.g. `[1]` and `[2]` are two elements and not one? Shouldn't the right part of my regex match `[1]` and `[2]` at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash is used in regex to escape things. `\"` just means a `"`, you want a blackslash followed by a double quote, which written like  `\\"`.

This is a bit more flexible expression allowing all kinds of escapes:

```
(?:[^" \\]|\\.)+|"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"
```

Comment: Thank you, I corrected my expression with your hint :-) I am out of practice and would have to think too much about your one :P